# Error with Inserting item into Room database - only inserting the last item and duplicating the rest

Tags: android, database, insert, android-room

My program is having an issue I don't know how to resolve it.I have a loop that inserts items into room database, but it only inserts the last (as seen in my logcat) item in the list and duplicates instead of showing them all, Like this:

List 1:
"Helo"
"my"
"world"

List 2: (inserted)
"world"
"world"
"world"

I don't know what could be causing the problem. Please tell me If you have any ideas about what's causing it. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the code that you're using to insert them

Comment: Actually, I solved the problems. It's about adding new item columns(?) in the repository. Thanks for sparking the light though. :)